# Keep getting 400 Invalid File Form error from Whisper API

Tags: java, android, openai-api, chatgpt-api, whisper

I am trying to call Whisper API from my android app. I am recording the audio and storing in `.wav` format. when i am calling the whisper API its always giving me 400 error saying invalid file format.

I tried playing the audio back and its working. also file is readable. have been trying to find solution for couple of hours now.

following is my code

```java
private void startRecording() {
        fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.wav";

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.start();
    }
```

```java
private void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;

        // Copy the recorded WAV file to a new file
        String newFileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/new_recording.wav";
        try {
            Files.copy(Paths.get(fileName), Paths.get(newFileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        File file = new File(newFileName);
        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", "new_recording.wav", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/wav"), new File(absolutePath)))
                .addFormDataPart("model", "whisper-1")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions")
                .post(requestBody)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer sk-QAym*******gUIRdxXGq")
                .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Unexpected code " + response);
                }
                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
```

was just trying to create another wav file from existing, and this is also not working.

would appreciate any help or suggestions.

thanks